# Cannot rewrite goal with assertion?

Tags: coq

I am not sure I understand why in some cases rewriting `H` works, and in some it doesnt.
Here for example:

```
Theorem add_assoc2 : forall n m: nat, n + m = m + n.
Proof. intros. rewrite add_comm. reflexivity. Qed.

Theorem plus_4: forall n m p q: nat,
  n + (n * p) + m + (m * p) = n + m + (n * p) + (m * p).
Proof.
  intros.
  assert (H: n * p + m = m + n * p).
  {  rewrite <- add_assoc2. reflexivity. }
  rewrite H.
```

Gives:

```
1 goal
n, m, p, q : nat
H : n * p + m = m + n * p
______________________________________(1/1)
n + n * p + m + m * p = n + m + n * p + m * p
```

But Coq complains: `Found no subterm matching "n * p + m" in the current goal.`
Why?

I clearly see one, on the left side. When using induction, rewriting with `IHn` doesn't pose any problem, even if there are some other terms in front of rewriteable expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "see" a subterm `n * p + m`, but this is misleading: Coq doesn't show you the implicit parentheses around all the `+` expressions.

Use

```
Set Printing Parentheses.
```

to make them visible. Your proof state is really:

```
  n, m, p, q : nat
  H : ((n * p) + m) = (m + (n * p))
  ============================
  (((n + (n * p)) + m) + (m * p)) = (((n + m) + (n * p)) + (m * p))
```

Coq was right that there is no subterm that matches `H`'s left hand side expression `((n * p) + m)`. You need to rewrite using some associativity lemmas to shift the parentheses around.

Also, `add_assoc2` is not a good name for a lemma `forall n m: nat, n + m = m + n`. This is a **commutativity** property, not associativity.